# Why is Ruby seeing `A.run` in class B as a constant and not a class?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, scope, constants

so this is my first question on stack overflow and I am new to Ruby, so if this is a simple question, please be nice.

I am starting off in OOP and making a game. What I think is wrong is that Ruby is thinking that a different class is a constant in the current class.

Here is my code:

**./a.rb**

```
require "./b"

class A
  class << self

    def run
      puts "A ran."
    end

  end

end
```

**./b.rb**

```
class B                                                                                                                                                                        
  require './a'

  def test 
    A.run
  end  

end  

b = B.new
b.test
```

When I run `ruby b.rb`, I get:

```
/Users/alexstriff/Dropbox/Code/ruby/ex45/b.rb:5:in `test': uninitialized constant B::A (NameError)                                                                             
      from /Users/alexstriff/Dropbox/Code/ruby/ex45/b.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
      from /Users/alexstriff/Dropbox/Code/ruby/ex45/a.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
      from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
      from b.rb:2:in `<class:B>'
      from b.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

So why is `A.run` seen as a constant by `class B`, instead of as a class?

**Edit:**

Could it possibly be a problem with the 'circular require'? I ran this under `ruby -w` and that came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned in your edit, I believe your issue is with a circular require. As you can see, when you run `ruby b.rb`, you require a.rb, which then requires b.rb again, etc. Instead, I would advise removing the `require` in a.rb, as it does not seem to depend on b.rb.

As a separate issue, I think the error you are getting is because you don't specify that `A` is a top-level class. Also, having the require inside of `class B` does not make `A` accessible inside `B`, so I would move it outside instead:

```
require './a'

class B
  def test
    ::A.run
  end
end

b = B.new
b.test
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responce.I actually had the `require` there when testing another problem and it seems I forgot that it would cause problems.

Comment: @jfjhh No problem, glad you fixed the issue!